TensorFlow Lite (TFLite) runPoseNetOnFrame returns empty recognitions in Flutter
I'm developing a Flutter application that utilizes TensorFlow Lite for pose detection using the tflite package. I'm encountering an issue where runPoseNetOnFrame returns empty recognitions ([]) despite passing valid camera image data.
// Initialization and camera setup
CameraController? controller;

void initializeCamera() async {
  // Check camera availability
  if (widget.cameras == null || widget.cameras!.isEmpty) {
    print('No camera found');
    return;
  }

  // Initialize CameraController
  controller = CameraController(
    widget.cameras![0], // Using the first camera
    ResolutionPreset.high,
  );

  try {
    await controller!.initialize();
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error initializing camera: $e');
    return;
  }

  // Start camera stream
  controller!.startImageStream((CameraImage img) {
    // Perform pose detection
    Tflite.runPoseNetOnFrame(
      bytesList: img.planes.map((plane) => plane.bytes).toList(),
      imageHeight: img.height,
      imageWidth: img.width,
      numResults: 1,
      rotation: -90,
      threshold: 0.2,
      nmsRadius: 10,
    ).then((recognitions) {
      if (recognitions != null && recognitions.isNotEmpty) {
        // Process recognitions
        print('Recognitions: $recognitions');
      } else {
        print('No recognitions found');
      }
    }).catchError((e) {
      print('Error running pose detection: $e');
    });
  });
}


When facing the issue where the bounding boxes (BndBox) are not drawn because the recognitions value is not reaching the camera widget
github repo link:https://github.com/aylinmercan/Yoga.dart/blob/1fe576134ede29b0b93b4c5b8bea0a0d6d32c98e/lib/yoga_detect/cameracontroller.dart#L51
Recognitions returns : []
